# What is this bushy, yellow-flowering plant?

Tags: identification, herbs

Can you help me identify this plant?

It is between a foot and two tall. It has a scent I can't really place. It doesn't seem strong enough for a mint.

[image]

Comment: I don't recognise what it is, but I can tell you it definitely isn't mint of any description, and may not even be an edible plant.

Comment: @Stephie it's indeed Lanzarote. I debated whether to add that information, sorry. The plant has been completely dead all the 6 months I've been here (when it was hot and extremely dry), but after the recent rainfalls it started to grow and blossom.

Answer (score 2):

Try Turnera.
http://www.google.com/search?q=turnera&tbm=isch

A few of my Turnera ulmifolia photos: 
http://www.henriettes-herb.com/plants/turnera/ulmifolia.html
Although this could be a different species of Turnera.

Comment: Can you improve this answer by adding why you think it matches a turnera?